# React Native JayData XML DOM parser not supported

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, react-native, jaydata

Im new to javascript and react-native and im trying to build a client which consume oData. By trying of executing jayDatas function initService I got the following error message:

```
{ message: 'XML DOM parser not supported',
  srcText: '',
  errorXmlText: '',
  request: 
   { requestUri: 'https://my322506.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cust/v1/demoapp/$metadata',
     method: 'GET',
     headers: 
      { Authorization: 'Basic Y2dyOjF6M2k3bU05',
        Accept: 'application/xml',
        'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0' },
     recognizeDates: false,
     callbackParameterName: '$callback',
     formatQueryString: '$format=json',
     enableJsonpCallback: false,
     async: true },
  response:
{ requestUri: 'https://my322506.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cust/v1/demoapp/$metadata',
     statusCode: 200,
     statusText: undefined,
     headers: 
      [ 'c4c-odata-response-time': '691  ms',
        dataserviceversion: '1.0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml' ],

...
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
XML DOM parser not supported`
```

My Code:

```
jayData
  .initService('https://my322506.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/cust/v1/demoapp/', credentials)
  .then(function (remoteDB, contextFactory, contexType) {
    console.log('HELLO');
  });
```

The error comes from the file jaydata-odatajs\lib\xml.js Line 190
Code:

```
function xmlParse(text) {
var domParser = undefined;
if (utils.inBrowser()) {
    domParser = window.DOMParser && new window.DOMParser();
} else {
    domParser = new (require('xmldom').DOMParser)();
}
var dom;

if (!domParser) {
    dom = msXmlParse(text);
    if (!dom) {
        xmlThrowParserError("XML DOM parser not supported0");
    }
    return dom;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got fixed it.
JayData mean we are in browser and try to get the parser out of the window, but there is no parser in window.
So I just set in window the DOMParser and it works.

```
export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
   constructor(props)
   {
       super(props);
       window.DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
```

Thanks!